# Negative lookahead to ignore boilerplate text in an email thread

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to write a negative lookahead for a regular expression that will ignore lines of boilerplate in the text of an email, specifically the bit that goes like:

```
> On Sat, Apr 27, 2013 at 11:39 PM, Jane Smith <jane.smith@example.com> wrote:
```

I want to match all the digits that are not in my negative lookahead. I tried this:

```
(?!(?:^>?*\sOn\s.*wrote:\s?)$)\d
```

But that always matches inside that line. I'm particularly confused because this regex:

```
(?:^>?*\sOn\s.*wrote:\s?)$
```

matches that entire line. Obviously I'm missing something, but I have no idea what it is. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you want to match?

Comment: In this case, I want to match all digits that aren't in a line that begins with "> On" and ends with "wrote:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this pattern, but don't forget to remove the empty matches:

```
> On .*+\n> wrote:|(\d++)
```

Comment: Hmm. I suppose this could work, but isn't negative lookahead designed specifically for these sorts of instances? If I did go this route, how would I know, if there were multiple instances of "On ... wrote:" throughout the document, which of all the matches needed to be discarded?

Comment: you know which of all because you use a capture group. In results, when "> On...wrote:" match the capture group is empty.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! I was playing with this all day, finally got it working. I wish I could get negative lookahead working, since this seems like the ideal use case, but... if it works, it works! Really appreciate the help.